# Is it possible to add bootstrap-tagsinput to textarea?

Tags: bootstrap-tags-input

I'm working on project and I want to add tagsinputs to a textarea. Is it possible somehow ? Thank for helping.

Comment: I solved it by removing borders from input and adding border to parent element so it looks like tagsinputs in textarea.

Comment: Taegost, I checked the documentation of bootsrap-tagsinput and looked for an answer here on stakoverflow, if it is what are you asking about )))

Answer (score 0):

There is not yet any support for this in Textare elements.One way to go is to use the input element for the tags.

See here for reference: https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/issues/38

Comment: thanks for answer. I solved it by css. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing borders from input and adding border to parent element so it looks like tagsinputs in textarea.